# jqgrid server side error message/validation handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In my json responses, I have 'STATUS' and 'errors' properties.
How can use this errors properties with jqGRid. To parse all errors and show them in a dialog box.

Basically just check, if status:'ERROR' then display all errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

In the last part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853457/jquery-jqgrid-renders-empty-table/6905206#6905206) to your previous question I tried already tried to give the answer on your current question. Probably I expressed me not clear enough.

You should not place and information about the error inside of the standard successful response. You should just follow main rules of the HTTP protocol used for communication between the server and the client.

The loading data in the grid, editing of the rows and all Ajax communication with the server are implemented with respect of HTTP protocol. Every HTTP response has *the status code* in the first line of the response. It's very important to understand the meaning of this.

The typical successful request with JSON data looks as following

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: application/json
...

{"page":"1",....}
```

If the URL which try to load not exist for example the first line of the server response will be

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

and jqGrid **based on the HTTP status code** (404 in the case) *will not try to interpret the the server response as the data which contains data with the grid content.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestError.htm) has the following code

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'Unknown.json', // there are no file with the name
    datatype: 'json',
    // ... some other typical parameters
    loadComplete: function () {
        alert("OK");
    },
    loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
              'textStatus: ' + textStatus + '\n' +
              'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        alert('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

which display the alert message like the following:

[image]

Moreover in the `jqXHR.responseText` you will find **the full body of the server response** as as string. The next alert shows the response.

With all above information I wanted to show you that error responses and successful responses will be processed in another way by the whole stack of software which you use (jqGrid, jQuery, `XMLHttpRequest` object, ...). So you should just use [error HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4) in the server responses if the error will be detected. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) for example you will see how to do this in case of the usage ASP.NET MVC.

[Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestErrorInDiv.htm) you can find another version of the `loadError` implementation which wait the input in the JSON form: `{"Source":"some error source",Message:"Description of the error"}`, and the error output will be like here

[image]

but the code can display additionally HTML response generated by your web server:

[image]

You can easy modify the code to your purpose. The code you can find below

```
loadComplete: function () {
    // remove error div if exist
    $('#' + this.id + '_err').remove();
},
loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // remove error div if exist
    $('#' + this.id + '_err').remove();

    // insert div with the error description before the grid
    $(this).closest('div.ui-jqgrid').before(
        '<div id="' + this.id + '_err" style="max-width:' + this.style.width +
            ';"><div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding:0.7em;float:left;">' +
            decodeErrorMessage(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) +
            '</div><div style="clear:left"/></div>'
    );
}
```

where the `decodeErrorMessage` function defined as

```
var decodeErrorMessage = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var htmlBody, errorInfo, i, errorText = '',
            errorIconSpan = '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; display: inline-block; margin-right: .3em;"></span>';
        if (textStatus) {
            errorText = textStatus;
        }
        if (errorThrown) {
            if (errorText.length > 0) {
                errorText += '<hr/>';
            }
            errorText += errorThrown;
        }
        if (typeof (jqXHR.responseText) === "string") {
            if (jqXHR.responseText.charAt(0) === '[') {
                try {
                    errorInfo = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                    errorText = "";
                    for (i = 0; i < errorInfo.length; i += 1) {
                        if (errorText.length !== 0) {
                            errorText += "<hr/>";
                        }
                        errorText += errorInfo[i].Source + ": " + errorInfo[i].Message;
                    }
                } catch (e) { }
                errorText = errorIconSpan + errorText;
            } else {
                htmlBody = /<body.*?>([\s\S]*)<\/body>/i.exec(jqXHR.responseText);
                if (htmlBody !== null && htmlBody.length > 1) {
                    errorText = htmlBody[1];
                }
            }
        } else {
            errorText = errorIconSpan + errorText;
        }
        return '<div style="float:left">' + errorText + '</div>';
    };
```

**UPDATE**: [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) contains *default implementation* of `loadError` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/js/grid.base.js#L2663-L2720) and [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/js/grid.base.js#L2810)), which generates relatively readable error message in case of the most Ajax errors. It displays the resulting text in the error div, existing above the body of the grid. Thus it's recommended to test, whether the default behavior produce good results before usage of custom `loadError`. If you really need to create your own `loadError` then you can place the error message in the error div using `displayErrorMessage` method of free jqGrid: `$("#grid").jqGrid("displayErrorMessage", customErrorMessage);`

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're describing, the easiest way is to add custom properties to the *data* json object that is being retrieved by the jqgrid from the server. Then you can capture those custom properties with the [loadComplete(data)](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) event.

```
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid({
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        //access data.propertyname here
    }
});
```