# jsonReader Configuration for jqGrid

Tags: javascript, html, json, jqgrid, jsonreader

I'm trying render data in my Jqgrid, but it is just not showing up. My Json data comes from a web server so I'm trying to use Jsonreader as a function to format my data. Can any1 point my mistakes out please. Thanks in advance.

here is my code for the jqgrid

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
url: 'localhost/webair/contactinfoes',
datatype: 'json',
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },

colNames: ['Company','Firstname','Job Title','Last Update Time', 'Last Update User',
'Lastname', 'Uuid'],      
colModel: [
    { name: 'comapany', width: 100},
    { name: 'firstname', width: 60},
    { name: 'jobtitle', width: 100},
    { name: 'lastupdatetime', width: 250, align: 'right' },
    { name: 'lastupdateuser', width: 100, align: 'right' },
    { name: 'lastname', width: 60 },
    { name: 'uuid', width: 250},

],
jsonReader: {
repeatitems: false,
root: function (obj) { return obj; },
page: function (obj) { return 1; },
total: function (obj) { return 1; },
records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
},
rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
pager: '#pager10',
viewrecords: true,
caption:"Terry's table",
}).navGrid('#gridpager');
})
```

and here is my json information;

```
[ {
"cel":"asdf",
"company":"adsf",
"fax":"asdf",
"firstname":"asdf",
"id":98304,
"jobTitle":"asdf",
"lastUpdateTime":1331831984277,
"lastUpdateUser":"anonymousUser",
"lastname":"berk",
"phone":"adsf",
"uuid":"2asa8a2-d2b5-48a2-ba35-b0cfasdf3170f",
"version":0}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small trailing comma error at the end of `colModel` is probably not the main error which you has.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BerkYazicioglu.htm) which uses practically your code shows, that the grid should be displayed. It it don't displayed you should include `loadError` callback function (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935)). I suppose that you will have "parsing error" exception which means that you get wrong 'Content-Type' HTTP header value in the server response.