# JQGrid data not loading on page load

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I am using [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/)

I have it on 2 domains (same code)... On domain 1, I have not problems with the loading of data when the page loads.

On Domain 2 I have the exact same code but with a problem.

When the page loads it won't load the data but when I click the refresh button on JQGrid the data loads fine but never during page load.

I've looked at the code and it seems the same to me.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could make this strange thing happen?

I've run out of ideas on where to look.

Comment: You should post the code which you use. The problem is *in the code*. In any way I would strictly recommend you to include `loadError` handle in the code. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run fiddler and see whats causing the issue.

Comment: does your ajax call return data ?

Comment: No, no data is being loaded. The problem is that the same exact code works fine in the other domain :o/

Comment: did you put a break point in your ajax method in c#/vb and see actually if it hits the breakpoint ? Code can work on one domain and the same code might not work on another. There could be many reasons for that. Did you deploy the dlls correctly, did you update your webconfig pointing to correct database server with correct settings etc.

Comment: Yes, it's all configured correctly. Whenever I click the reload button on the grid the data loads fine. It's just not loading when I reload the whole page

Comment: Maybe, there's a way of clicking on the ID of the refresh button after the grid loads?

Comment: that will be a hack but if you want to do that you can use jquery and do something like this $("#buttonid").trigger('click');

Comment: I tried that but I need to get it to do that after the grid loads. Don't know how to get that though

Comment: use loadComplete event of Jqgrid.

Comment: Trying this but does not work: <script>
 $("#list").jqGrid({loadComplete: 
         function() {
              alert('load complete')
            }
});

</script>

Comment: I think you should post full code in seprate thread for this I am sure someone will have a solution.