# Reading json on jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have json like

```
{
    "total": 7,
    "rows": [ 
        {"ID": "1","Code": "Code1" },
        { "ID": "2","Code": "Code2"},
        { "ID": "3", "Code": "Code3" },
        { "ID": "4", "Code": "Code4"},
        {"ID": "5","Code": "Code5"},
        {"ID": "6","Code": "Code6"},        
        {"ID": "7","Code": "Code7" }  
    ]
}
```

and I want to read this in jqGrid

I used in grid with

```
colNames: ['Code'], 
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Code', width: 100 }],


jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "rows", root: function (obj) { return obj; } }.
```

but it dosn't work

Comment: Please specify if you are going to use local or remote data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the usage of

```
jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "ID"}
```

should be enough if you use `loadonce: true` additionally (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ahmedosman.htm)). From the other side if you try to implement *server side data paging* you should extend the JSON data. By the way the current value of `total` corresponds to `records` input property. The `total` property should have the value of the total *pages* and not the total record number.

You don't posted the whole code which defines the grid. So you can has more errors as you posted. In any way I would recommend you to use `loadError` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

root shoud be rows, not object.

```
root: "rows"
```

or

```
root: function(obj) { return obj.rows; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json reader will be like this:

```
jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "ID", root: "rows",cell:"code" }
```