# JQGrid populated with blank rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have created the Grid with the following configuration

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "populateAllRulesJson.action",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",   
        success: function(result)
        {
             alert("SUCCESS ::: " + JSON.stringify(result.jSONResponseObject));
             data = JSON.stringify(result.jSONResponseObject);
             jQuery("#rulesTable").jqGrid({
                    url:"populateAllRulesJson.action",
                    datatype: "jsonstring", 
                    height: 'auto', 
                    width: 'auto', 
                    colNames:['Rule ID','Description', 'Geograph', 'Process', 'Rules Classification', 'Types', 'UDAC'], 
                    colModel:[ {name:'ruleID',index:'ruleID', width:65, sorttype:'int'}, 
                               {name:'description',index:'description', width:150}, 
                               {name:'geograph',index:'geograph', width:100},
                               {name:'process',index:'process', width:100},            
                               {name:'rulesClassification',index:'rulesClassification', width:100},
                               {name:'types',index:'types', width:100},
                               {name:'udac',index:'udac', width:100}
                             ], 
                    datastr : data,
                    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                    rowNum:10, 
                    rowList : [10,20,30], 
                    loadonce:true, 
                    mtype: "GET", 
                    rownumbers: true, 
                    rownumWidth: 10, 
                    gridview: true, 
                    pager: '#rulesDivPager', 
                    sortname: 'ruleID', 
                    viewrecords: true, 
                    sortorder: "asc", 
                    caption: "Searching Rules ..."

                });
        },
        error: function(x, e)
        {
            alert(x.readyState + " "+ x.status +" "+ e.msg);
        }

});
```

I am sending the following JSON object to the grid. But the grid is populating with four blank rows.

```
{
"total":2,
"page":1,
"records":7,
"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":"{\"ruleID\":\"43\",\"description\":\"Images, text and voice over should synchronize as best as possible.\",\"geograph\":\"Yell US\",\"process\":\"Photomotion\",\"rulesClassification\":\"Image\",\"types\":\"New\",\"udac\":\"NPM\"}"},
{"id":"2","cell":"{\"ruleID\":\"48\",\"description\":\" For profile pages UDAC Mismatch in a Control sheet can be ignored.\",\"geograph\":\"Yell US\",\"process\":\"Profile Pages\",\"rulesClassification\":\"Copysheet\",\"types\":\"New\",\"udac\":\"NGP\"}"},
{"id":"3","cell":"{\"ruleID\":\"51\",\"description\":\" Ignore all requests for logo sized artwork in NSP ads.\",\"geograph\":\"Yell US\",\"process\":\"Profile Pages\",\"rulesClassification\":\"Logo\",\"types\":\"New\",\"udac\":\"NSP\"}"},
{"id":"4","cell":"{\"ruleID\":\"47\",\"description\":\" Irregular borders are not allowed in banner ads..\",\"geograph\":\"Yell US\",\"process\":\"Profile Pages\",\"rulesClassification\":\"Border\",\"types\":\"New\",\"udac\":\"MRB\"}"}
]}
```

What was the mistake i made in this grid configuration. please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your main error is the usage of `cell` as *string*. You have

```
{"id":"1","cell":"{\"ruleID\":\"43\", ...}"},
```

instead of

```
{"id":"1","cell":{"ruleID":"43", ...}},
```

The second problem is that you use some very strange format of input data. In general you can specify the format of input data with `jsonReader` option. If you don't use any `jsonReader` the default value will be used (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data)). So the value of `cell` property must be **array** of items:

```
{"id":"1","cell":["43", ...., "New","NPM"]},
```

You can reduce the need of sending `"id"` (especially with *dummy values* which are not equal `ruleID`) and sending fixed text `"cell"` in every row of data. In the case you can specify `jsonReader: {cell: "", id: 0}` and the data direct as array:

```
["43", ...., "New","NPM"]
```

The usage `id: 0` means that the first element of the array specify unique rowid.

Alternatively you can use `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "ruleID"}` and send the items as object with named properties:

```
{"ruleID":"43", ....,"types":"New","udac":"NPM"}
```

So you have many options, but your current format of JSON data is definitively wrong and you have to change it.

Moreover I think that you should better use `datatype: "json"` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"`. If you do use `datatype: "jsonstring"` you can use `datastr : result.jSONResponseObject`. The `datastr` must not be JSON string. It could be object.

The last remark: I recommend you to use `loadError` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) for more details.