# jqGrid catch exception while creating definition

Tags: exception, jqgrid, error-handling, overlay

I want to catch errors while creating jqGrid definition like mismatch of col_names and col_model or errors while cell custom formatting.  `The purpose is to catch these errors and display as an overlay` over grid placeholder.
If I place `try catch outside grid definition` , control never comes in catch block but error is by default shown as alert dialog.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the example with mismatching of the size of `colNames` and `colModel` is not good example. Is you use `cn` and `cm` for example as the values of `colNames` and `colModel` parameters you can just include `if (cn.length !== cm.length) {...}`  in your code *before* you create jqGrid. The current code of jqGrid do the same (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L945-L948)).

In general there are no common way how jqGrid or other plugins reports errors. jQuery for example introduces [jQuery.error](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.error/) function which you can overwrite in general. The problem is that the function will be used in *very small subset* of jQuery code. So it can't really help in my opinion. The most jQuery functions has no validation of input parameters. So you can have unpredictable results if you use wrong parameters.

Moreover many parts of jqGrid code works **asynchronously**. So one should make validation mostly in other way. I recommend you for example to use `loadError` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) for more details.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Oleg! I understand that I have to handle different grid events for different errors. The links covers most of them. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Seedika: You are welcome! If you use other features of jqGrid there are corresponding additional features which allows you to customize reporting of error. For example form editing has [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback and so on.