# jquery jqgrid list delete data aftersubmit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

What I want to ask is that I have a jqgrid list and i want to get error message on screen in case deletion fails. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'../listeAjax',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['Id','Hizmet adı', 'Sektörler', 'Durum', 'Düzenle'], 
        colModel:[
            {name:'onto_data_id',index:'onto_data_id', width:55, editable: false},
            {name:'baslik',index:'baslik', editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, formoptions:{ elmprefix:"(*)"}},
            {name:'sektor_list',index:'sektor_list', editable:false},
            {name:'is_active',index:'is_active', align: 'center', editable:true, stype:'select', 
                editoptions:{value:":All;1:<?php echo lang('title_aktif')?>;0:<?php echo lang('title_pasif')?>", defaultValue:1},
                edittype:"select"   
            },
            {name:'duzenle',index:'duzenle', align: 'center', sortable:false, search: false, editable:false}        
        ],
        rowNum: <?php echo DEFAULT_GRID_ROWNUM; ?>,
        rowList:[100,200,400,800],
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'onto_data_id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        multiselect: true,
        width: 800,
        height: "100%",
        editurl: '../islemAjax',
        caption: "Hizmetler",
        mtype: "GET",
        postData:{parent_id: '<?php echo $parent_id; ?>', parent_type: '<?php echo $parent_type; ?>'}
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
            {edit:true, add:true, del:true, search:false}, 
            {closeOnEscape:true, bottominfo:"<?php langValue('info_yildizlialanlar'); ?>",editData: {
                    parent_id: function() {
                    return '<?php echo $parent_id; ?>';
                },
                parent_type: function() {
                    return '<?php echo $parent_type; ?>';
                },
                tur: function() {
                    return '<?php echo ONTO_TYPE_HIZMET; ?>';
                }
            }}, 
            {
                beforeSubmit: function(postdata, formid){
                    var message;
                    $.ajax( {
                        type : 'POST',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        url : "<?php echo URL_YONETIMDATACONTROL; ?>",
                        data : 'baslik='+postdata.baslik + '&parent_id=' + <?php echo $parent_id; ?> + '&parent_type=' + <?php echo $parent_type; ?> + '&onto_type=' + <?php echo ONTO_TYPE_HIZMET  ; ?>,
                        async : false,
                        success : function(result) {
                            if(result.status == true) {                             
                                complete = true;
                            } else {
                                complete = false;
                            }
                            message = result.message;
                        },
                        error: function (data, status, e) {
                            complete = false;
                            message = e;
                        }

                    });

                    return [complete, message, ""];

                },

                closeOnEscape:true, bottominfo:"<?php langValue('info_yildizlialanlar'); ?>",editData: {
                    parent_id: function() {
                    return '<?php echo $parent_id; ?>';
                },
                parent_type: function() {
                    return '<?php echo $parent_type; ?>';
                },
                tur: function() {
                    return '<?php echo ONTO_TYPE_HIZMET; ?>';
                }
            }}, 
            {delData: {
                    parent_id: function() {
                        return '<?php echo $parent_id; ?>';
                    },
                    parent_type: function() {
                        return '<?php echo $parent_type; ?>';
                    }
            }}, 
            {} 
            );  
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar');
} );
</script>

<h1>
<?php echo langValue('title_hizmetliste'); ?> 
<?php 
if(isset($sektor_baslik)) 
{
    echo '(' . $sektor_baslik . ')';
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo URL_YONETIMHIZMETEKLE; ?>" title="<?php echo langValue('form_ekle')?>" class="tooltip">
    <img src="<?php echo PATH_MEDIA_IMG_YONETIM; ?>icons/8_48x48.png" alt="" />
</a>
</h1>
<div class="pad20">
    <?php if(isset($info)) { ?>
    <div class="message success close">
        <h2><?php echo $info; ?></h2>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div id="tabs">
        <!-- First tab -->
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <table id="list"></table>
            <div id="pager"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I inserted afterSubmit but it returns nothing. Moreover, when I alert a text in afterSubmit,  nothing happens. Here is the aftersubmit code I tried:

```
afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) 
{
     alert("test");                  
     return [success,message,new_id] 
}
```

What is wrong in here?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main cases in error handling of the server response: 1) the response contain some error HTTP code and 2) the response contains some successful HTTP code. In case of an successful response (from the HTTP code point of view) the callback `afterSubmit` will be executed. In case of an error response (from the HTTP code point of view) the callback `errorTextFormat` will be executed. So you need use something like

```
{
    delData: {
        parent_id: function() {
            return '<?php echo $parent_id; ?>';
        },
        parent_type: function() {
            return '<?php echo $parent_type; ?>';
        }
    },
    errorTextFormat: function (jqXHR) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        return "Error code: " + data.status + ", Description: " + jqXHR.responseText;
    }
}
```

The exact code of `errorTextFormat` depend on the content of the `jqXHR.responseText` in case of error. In many cases it's better to use only subset of `jqXHR.responseText` to have the mostly readable results. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935).

I would recommend you to test always not only the case where the error response will be explicitly produced by your code, but two additional cases: 1) common server error (for example if you would use non-existing `url` for delete operation) 2) client side error like timeout from the server.

Comment: ok I tried it but still it doesn't work. php code returns false / 0. But alert(jqXHR.responseText); alerts nothing. Moreover, there is no error in console.

Comment: @OnurGöker: I wrote you before that the exact content of response depend on your server code. In any way either `afterSubmit` or `errorTextFormat` callback will be called. The first parameter is [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which is superset of `XMLHTTPRequest`. It contains the mostly full information about the server response. I recommend you to examine the HTTP response with respect of Fiddler2, Firebug or Developer Tools of IE or Chrome and compare the results with `jqXHR` inside of any debugger. You should able to fine all information in the `jqXHR`.

Comment: According to chrome console, response is 0.

Comment: @OnurGöker: What you mean under "response"? How HTTP response looks like (HTTP status code, HTTP headers, HTTP body, ...)? I wrote that `jqXHR` is object. `jqXHR.responseText` contains typically HTTP body. In some cases `jqXHR.responseText` is undefined (it's mostly in case of client side Ajax errors). What is "0"? Is it `jqXHR.responseText`? In any way it's what your server returns. Is the result different from successful response?