# Ajax grid Options and postData

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

i have a problem here, i used postdata to send parameters from ASPX file to the webservice, without using `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}`.

The problem is, the grid does not display the contents from the webservice and once we use this `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}` the grid does not pass any of the parameters  to the webservice. Here is our jqgrid code, please help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var myGrid = $("#list");
  myGrid.jqGrid({
    url: '/priParentsContribution.asmx/getListOfTeachers',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    //ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
    jsonReader: {
      repeatitems: true,
      root: "d.rows",
      page: "d.page",
      total: "d.total",
      records: "d.records"
    },
    colModel: [{
        name: 'feePurpose',
        index: 'feePurpose',
        width: 100,
        editable: true,
        edittype: 'select',
        editoptions: {
          value: "0:--Select--;Books:Books;Uniform:Uniform"
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'standard1',
        index: 'standard1',
        width: 100,
        editable: true
      }, {
        name: 'standard2',
        index: 'standard2',
        width: 100,
        editable: true
      }, {
        name: 'standard3',
        index: 'standard3',
        width: 100,
        editable: true
      }, {
        name: 'standard4',
        index: 'standard4',
        width: 100,
        editable: true
      }, {
        name: 'standard5',
        index: 'standard5',
        width: 100,
        editable: true
      }, {
        name: 'standard6',
        index: 'standard6',
        width: 100,
        editable: true
      }, {
        name: 'standard7',
        index: 'standard7',
        width: 100,
        editable: true
      }
    ],
    forceFit: true,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: "#pager",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    width: 1200,
    height: 300,
    loadonce: true, //THIS IS IMPORTANT !!!
    postData: {
      advertiserID: function () {
        return $("#advertiserId").val();
      },
    },
    ajaxGridOptions: {
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (data, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == "success") {
          var thegrid = myGrid[0];
          thegrid.addJSONData(data.d);
          thegrid.grid.hDiv.loading = false;
          switch (thegrid.p.loadui) {
          case "disable":
            break;
          case "enable":
            $("#load_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
            break;
          case "block":
            $("#lui_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
            $("#load_" + thegrid.p.id).hide();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    ajaxGridOptions: {
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      cach: false
    },
    //rowNum: 100,
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
      var propertyName, propertyValue, dataToSend = {};
      for (propertyName in postData) {
        if (postData.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
          propertyValue = postData[propertyName];
          if ($.isFunction(propertyValue)) {
            dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue();
          } else {
            dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue
          }
        }
      }
      return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
    }    
  });
  $("#reload").click(function () {
    myGrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
  });
  myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: true,
    search: false,
    search: false,
    view: false
  });
  myGrid.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager');
});
```

Comment: You included in the code `ajaxGridOptions` option **twice**. You should don't overwrite default `success` callback of jQuery.ajax with youth in `ajaxGridOptions`. You should include `loadError` callback (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935)) to know *which error* you have. You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) of Developer Tools (press F12 in IE to start) to trace HTTP traffic. You will see whether the request will be send to the server, whether the server respond and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You have to nodes : **ajaxGridOptions** into your jqGrid options object.