# How to investigate with jqgrid when the form editing doesn't work?

Tags: jqgrid

What is the best way to search why the form editing doesn't work anymore ?
I am using the 3.6 version and didn't change the code.
The events are executed (beforeinitdata, beforeshowform,...) but the url never executed and the form never displayed.
Any ideas how to investigate ?

Comment: You should *debug* the problem in Developer Tools of IE, Firebug or something like that. Usage of jqGrid 3.6 now is the same as working on computer running Windows NT 3.5. Supporting of such platform is typically much more expensive as upgrade to resent version. I recommend you to use version 4.5.2.

Comment: I understand your point of view but I don't want to add problems to my problems. The code using the 3.6 version was good. I probably changed something in my environment which disturb jqgrid. I tried to debug with firebug (breakpoints in events) but I didn't find why the form is never displayed and the url never executed. Do you suggest to enter in the jqgrid code ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that somebody can help you based on the information which you posted. Moreover you posted your question on stackoverflow, but the goal of it is sharing of *common question* and *common solutions*. Do you believe that there are many other people who have interest in version 3.6? So what you want is debugging of your *specific* solution for free. I think that stackoverflow is wrong place for such requests.

Comment: But there is my friend Oleg who often solved our problems ! I think that my question is independant of the jqgrid version because my problem is outside jqgrid. Anyway, I thought that tricks (tracing, etc) were possible to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I don't recommend you to use jqGrid 3.6**. It's more as 3,5 years old which is half an eternity in web development.

If you do had old version of the code which worked previously and it don't work now you should first verify which version of jQuery and jQuery UI you use. jqGrid 3.6 is tested with jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.7.2. If you use more recent version of jQuery you can have compatibility problems.

Independent from the version of jqGrid which you use I would recommend you to use `loadError` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) for details. It helps to to find the reason why Ajax call can fail.

Debugging of jqGrid 3.6 should be done in another way as now: there are no `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. You have to include separate modules `grid.base.js`, `jquery.fmatter.js`, `grid.custom.js`, `grid.common.js`, `grid.formedit.js` and so on instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. If you opens `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and search for `Modules:` you will find the order. You have to include the modules `grid.base.js`, `jquery.fmatter.js`, ... in exact the same order instead of usage `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. Then you can debug the code near `$.ajax` calls.

Comment: OK, I will follow your advice. Does jqGrid 4.5.2 always use the jQuery included in the download (1.9.0 version) ?

Comment: @Bertaud: If you use jqGrid 4.5.2 you can use jQuery from 1.3.2 till 2.0.1. jqGrid try to don't use no new features of new version of jQuery, but one have to adjust the code of jqGrid so that it is compatible to new version of jQuery.