# jQgrid: Data Not loaded

Tags: jquery, jsp, jqgrid

I am trying use jQgrid but the table cannot load the data. There is some sort of transaparent black block UI in the background. The Json response i received is:

```
          {"total":"1","page":"1","records ":"10",
        "rows":[
        {"id":"26010","cell":[26010,303,100,""]},
        {"id":"26009","cell":[26009,303,100,""]},
        {"id":"26008","cell":[26008,303,100,""]},
        {"id":"26007","cell":[26007,303,100,""]},
        {"id":"26006","cell":[26006,303,100,""]},
        {"id":"26005","cell":[26005,303,100,""]},
        {"id":"26004","cell":[26004,303,100,""]},
        {"id":"26003","cell":[26003,303,100,""]},
        {"id":"26002","cell":[26002,303,100,""]},
        {"id":"26001","cell":[26001,303,100,""]}]}
```

The page:

```
<table id="list3"></table>
<div id="pager3"></div>
<table id="navgrid"></table>
<div id="pagernav"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#list3").jqGrid({
        url:'<%=getForecastedTransactionURL%>',
        mtype:'POST',
        datatype : 'json',
        colNames : [ 'Txn Id', 'Transaction Type', 'Amount', 'Description'],
        colModel : [ {
            name : 'id',
            index : 'id',
            sorttype : "int",
            hidden:true
        }, {
            name : 'transactionType',
            index : 'transactionType',
            width : 100
        }, {
            name : 'amount',
            index : 'amount',
            width : 80,
            align : "right",
            sorttype : "number"
        }, {
            name : 'description',
            index : 'description',
            width : 80,
            align : "right",
            sorttype : "text"
        }],
        multiselect : true,
        rowNum : 20,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        pager : '#pager3',
        sortname : 'transactionType',
        viewrecords : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        loadonce : true,
        caption : "Load Once Example"
    });
});
</script>
```

Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript code which you use is correct and it corresponds to JSON data which returned from the server. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/aneal.htm) demonstrate that the code should work. In the demo I made only minor changes (added `height: "auto", gridview: true` option and increased width of `description` column to see the results in the pager more clear. I removed `mtype:'POST'` only because my demo loads the data directly from the file per HTTP GET). I recommend you to compare your demo with my. Additionally I recommend you to use `loadError` callback (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935)) which can help to diagnose errors during loading the grid. I hope that the error description will help you to find the error in your code. Typical error could be wrong `Content-Type` of HTTP response.

Additional small optimization which I suggest you is the following. The JSON format which you currently produce on the server contains many unneeded information and duplicates of `id` information. You included currently hidden `id` column which is not really required. Every row of jqGrid have `id` attribute. You can use the value instead of usage of unneeded hidden column. For example you can change your code to produce the data

```
[
    [303,100,"",26010],
    [303,100,"",26009],
    [303,100,"",26008],
    [303,100,"",26007],
    [303,100,"",26006],
    [303,100,"",26005],
    [303,100,"",26004],
    [303,100,"",26003],
    [303,100,"",26002],
    [303,100,"",26001]
]
```

add `jsonReader` option and change `colModel` to

```
colModel : [{
    name : 'transactionType',
    width : 100
}, {
    name : 'amount',
    width : 80,
    align : "right",
    sorttype : "number"
}, {
    name : 'description',
    width : 280,
    align : "right"
}],
jsonReader: {id: 3}
```

Such `jsonReader` specify that the 3-th element of item array is the `id` value. As the result you will have grid which looks exactly like the previous demo (see new demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/aneal1.htm)). The picture below shows that rowids are still set correctly

[image]