# How to display error message using MVC error handler(Customized) and jqgrid Load error trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I am working on ASP.net MVC 2.0 Application and using jqgrid in it.

I am using the following code to handle exceptions during ajax requests for loading grid

```
 loadError:function(xhr,status,error)
{
  alert("some thing wrong has happened"+xhr.responseTest);
}
```

This is showing alert when the error is raised during ajax requests.

But , here i dont want to use xhr.responseTest to show the error description , rather i am using Custom Error Handler that over rides the default HandleError attribute of MVC in the following manner:

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode() != 500)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!ExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(filterContext.Exception))
            {
                return;
            }

            // if the request is AJAX return JSON else view.
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
            {

                filterContext.Result = AjaxError(filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext);                                                
                //filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                //filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                //{
                //    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                //    Data = new
                //    {
                //        error = true,
                //        message = filterContext.Exception.Message
                //    }
                //};
            }
            else
            {
                var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
                var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
                var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = View,
                    MasterName = Master,
                    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                    TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
                };
            }
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        }

        protected JsonResult AjaxError(string message, ExceptionContext filterContext)          
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            message = "Something went wrong while processing your request. Please refresh the page and try again.";            
           filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;          
           filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;                    
           return new JsonResult {   Data = new{ ErrorMessage = message }, ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};}
    }
```

I am using [CustomHandleError] filter to handle exception for the controller action.

As, one can see if the request is an ajax request , i am throwing some json response containing the error information. (**Data(Error information) in the above code**)

I was getting the exact error information  into Data variable and setting up appropriate json error response,

But, the problem is i was not able to capture that json on client side and display that error message rather than using xhr.responseText.

I tried in the following way : but this does not work:

```
loadError:function(Error)
    {
      alert("some thing wrong has happened"+Error.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

The alert is coming as :

```
some thing wrong has happened+ **undefined**
```

it is not displaying error messsage rather displaying as Undefined which means that the json response from CustomError Handler is not recieced

Please help or give any sugesstions on how to implement above .

Comment: You use multiple times `xhr.responseTest` in the text??? Probably you mean `xhr.responseText`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback `loadError` contains the same parameters like the `error` callback of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): `jqXHR` of the type [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) (a superset of the [XMLHTTPRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object), the string `textStatus` and the string `errorThrown`. So to access to JSON response you should call `$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText)` explicitly. You can use `jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")` inside of `loadError` to validate additionally that you try to interpret the error response from the server as JSON response only if `"Content-Type"` is `"application/json"` or `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`. You can first verify that `jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")` returns string (and not `null` or `undefined`) and then use `.split(";")[0]` to get `"application/json"` part without `charset=utf-8`.

Comment: @Oleg..I am trying to find out the way to do this since ages..you just solved it in a minute..Thanks sir.

Comment: @Avinash: You are welcome! I just had the same problem before. I described some way which close to youth [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935). Later I improved the solution which I use myself by usage `jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")`. So I spend also many time to find the best way to solve the problem. In my answer I shared only my previous experience with you and other readers.