# Handle no records loading on Jqgrid when setGridParam, reloadGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a dropdown button where a user can select filters to filter jqgrid.

Here is what it looks like

```
jQuery("#filter_not_on_server").click(function (e) {
                jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: '<?php echo APP_URL; ?>/php/user/edit_appfilter.php?filter=true&server_filter=null', page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

So it works fine except when the filter returns no results. When that happens i get a "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error".

It is a good possibility in some cases so i would like to handle when that happens. I would simply like to clear the grid when that happens with no rows.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you should add `loadError` callback to jqGrid to handle the exception on the server. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) provides different implementations of `loadError`. You can include in your implementation any custom actions like clear the grid content using `clearGridData` method, displaying your custom message and so on.