# 415 Unsupported Media Type Error

Tags: jqgrid

I'm getting an error of 
"415 Unsupported media type". I've tried the solutions provided already.But my problem is not solved.

Here is my Code for receiving loading jason data dynamically in jqgrid

```
                jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({

                contentType: "application/json",
                datatype: "json",

                height: 250,



                colNames:['Workbook Name','Superior','Hierarchy','Usage', 'Created', 'Created by'],

                colModel:[                      

            {name:'name',index:'name', width:90,editable: true,formatter:function(rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {

                                return "<a href='1.1.1 Edit Workbook (Name).html' style='height:25px;width:120px;' type='button' >"+rawObject.name+"</a>";

                            },unformat:undoaddLink,search: true},

                            {name:'recordType',index:'recordType', width:90,formatter:function(rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {

                                return "<a href='#' type='button' >"+rawObject.recordType+"</a>";

                            },editable: true,editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' },unformat:undoaddLinkparent,search: true},

                            {name:'hierarchy',index:'hierarchy', width:150,editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' },formatter: setVal,search: true,unformat:undohierarchy},

                            {name:'usage',index:'usage', width:90,editable: true,editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' },search: true,formatter:ChangeVal},

                            {name:'created',index:'created', width:70,editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' },search: true},

                            {name:'createdBy',index:'createdBy', width:90,editable: true,editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' },search: true}

                ], 

                viewrecords : true,

                rowNum:10,

                rowList:[10,20,30],

                pager : pager_selector,

                altRows: true,



                'cellEdit': true,

                 'cellsubmit' : 'clientArray',

                editurl: 'clientArray',

                multiselect: true,

                multiboxonly: true,

                sortable: true,


              gridComplete: function() {

                 $("tr").not(':first').hover(

                 function () {

                  $(this).css("background","#CCCCFF");

                 }, 

                 function () {

                  $(this).css("background","");

                }

                );

                },


                loadComplete : function() {

                    var table = this;

                    setTimeout(function(){

                        styleCheckbox(table);


                        updateActionIcons(table);

                        updatePagerIcons(table);

                        enableTooltips(table);

                    }, 0);

                },



            });
```

I'm getting the jason data currectly in localhost.But in server I'm getting the error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should append your question with the JSON data returned from the server. You should format better the code which you post if you want that other people read it. About your code: it don't contains `url` parameter and `contentType` is unknown. You should use `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }` instead. If you need to send the parameter to `url` as JSON too then you should use `serializeGridData` callback like `serializeGridData: function (data) { return JSON.stringify(data); }` additionally.
}`.

Comment: The usage of `loadError` is recommended too (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935)). I recommend you additionally to verify that the server response contains `Content-Type: application/json` in HTTP header. You can use Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to trace HTTP traffic. The error "415 Unsupported media type" could mean that the server didn't set the header in the response.