# Table Using JQGrid in Extenal Javascript

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have following code for dispay items. like :-

[image]

```
function DisplayNewList()
{

                $("#list").jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'json',

                    url: 'Service.svc/json/getIngredients/',

                    mtype: 'GET',


                    colNames: ['Ingredents', 'Value'],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: 'Ingredents', index: 'Ingredents', width: 100 },
                        { name: 'value' }


                    ]
                });



}
```

I used the above jqgrid. But not getting table in proper place and not displaying any data on it.

I'm getting 2 cells(heading of table) in the bottom of my page. Not inside the box where i specified.

'list' is table id and it is there in .aspx file. The above code is there in external java script file.

Can you please tell me where to place jqgrid. and how to use it here.

Now Getting the table like this:-

[image]

For getIngredients I have Service Like this:-
IService:

```
[OperationContract]
         [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
          UriTemplate = "json/getIngredients",
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
         [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Status")]
         List<ItemList> GetIngredients;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should place empty table `<table id="list"></table>` inside of HTML fragment. You should convert the empty table to grid by usage `$("#list").jqGrid({...});` *after the `<table>` is already placed on the page*.

**UPDATED**: You have the problem with loading data from `url: kimsHost + 'Service.svc/json/getIngredients/'`. I recommend you to do the following:

1. Add `loadError` callback. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) for details.
2. Add the following options/callbacks:

```js
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
serializeRowData: function (data) {
    return JSON.stringify(data);
},
gridview: true,
autoencode: true
```

3. I recommend you to consider to use `loadonce: true` option. You should use it if the server returns **all data** and not implemented server side paging, sorting and filtering/searching.
4. I recommend to remove unneeded `index` properties from `colModel`, verify that `sortname: 'Timestamp'` is the option which you really need. You should remove trailing `,` at the end of `colModel`. The syntax `...},]` is error in JavaScript. The error will be ignored by most modern web browsers, but some web browsers, like IE8, can find it critical. It's better to fix syntax of JavaScript code.

Comment: Yes. Same thing I have done. The values inside jqgrid is not displaying. While debugging i will get 2 rows. But those are not displaying here.

Comment: @IMRUP: Where is the code which you use now? Do you see nothing or you see empty grid with column headers? Do you sure that `<table id="list"></table>` is already placed on the page at the moment? You can insert `alert($("#list").length);` directly before creating the grid. If alert displays 1 then the table is on the page. If you will see 0 then you try to create grid in the wrong moment.

Comment: <table id="list"></table> is there in aspx  and the grid is in external java script

Comment: @IMRUP:  see **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: I updated every unneeded code . I forgot to change here. My problem is , Now i cant display the data inside that table. Getting 2 rows of data, but its not displaying inside the table.

Comment: @IMRUP: Did you seem my previous comment? Do you included `loadError`, `ajaxGridOptions`, ... I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to trace HTTP traffic. You should append your question with exact response of the server.

Comment: Yes. Its not showing error. I added loadcomplete: function(){ alert("Function works");} and loaderror: .... It executed loadcomplete. and got alert function works.

Comment: @IMRUP: Sorry, but I don't want to repeat everything twice. **You need include the exact JSON response**.  By the way you should **not use `name: '%'`**. `name` value will be used to construct ids of HTML elements.

Comment: In my code i used value. The same name what i used in procedure. Im not able to display the data inside table. that is the problem

Comment: @IMRUP: `colModel` and `jsonReader` have to corresponds the format of JSON data. One can't help you without to see JSON data.