# Call WebMethod from jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, webmethod

I am learning `jqGrid` and following [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/771767/JqGrid-In-MVC-Basics). However demo is build in `Asp.Net MVC` and I am trying it using `Asp.Net WebForms`. My debugger is not stepping in into `WebMethod`

Here is my code

```
$("#tblDemo").jqGrid(
            {
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetGridData',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'EmloyeeId', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
                { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150 },
                { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150 }]
                , rowNum: 10,
                sortname: 'Id',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "List Employee Details",
                scrollOffset: 0
            });
```

The problem doesn't seems to be with `WebMethod` because it is being called if I use `$.ajax` (just to test `WebMethod`).  Still have a look at `WebMethod`.

Here are files I referenced.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="js/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" />
    <script src="js/js/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
```

There is no error on console. Please help me figure out this.

**Update 1**

Changed my jqGrid code as suggested. Now it look like this

```
$("#tblDemo").jqGrid(
            {
                url: '/Default.aspx/GetGridData',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',   
                colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
                loadonce : true,
                colModel: [
                { name: 'Id',  width: 20, stype: 'text' },
                { name: 'FirstName',  width: 150 },
                { name: 'LastName',  width: 150 }]
                , rowNum: 10,

                sortname: 'Id',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "List Employee Details",
                scrollOffset: 0,
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "d.rows",
                    page: "d.page",
                    total: "d.total",
                    records: "d.records"
                }
            });
```

I did not include definition of `GetData` because it was not causing problem as debugger was not even hitting first line of my `WebMethod`. Basically it is getting data from database into `DataTable`

```
[WebMethod]
        //[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string GetGridData()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetData());
        }

        public static DataTable GetData()
        {
            string conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConString"].ToString();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From MyTest",con))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

**Update 2**

As suggested by Oleg, I have changed my code as below

```
[WebMethod]
        //[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string GetGridData()
        {
             return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetData());
        }

        public static DataTable GetData()
        {
            string conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConString"].ToString();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From MyTest",con))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }



$("#tblDemo").jqGrid(
            {
                url: '/Default.aspx/GetGridData',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',   
                colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
                loadonce : true,
                colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', key: true, width: 20, stype: 'text' },
                { name: 'FirstName',  width: 150 },
                { name: 'LastName',  width: 150 }]
                , rowNum: 10,

                sortname: 'Id',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "List Employee Details",
                scrollOffset: 0,
                gridview: true,
                postData: "{}",
                autoencode: true,
                loadError : function(xhr,st,err) { 
                    alert("Type: "+st+"; Response: "+ xhr.status + " "+xhr.statusText);
                },
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: function (obj) {
                        return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d) : obj.d;
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Update 3**

Added screenshot on how demo shows response body

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't posted the server side code or at least the definition of `GetGridData`. Moreover you should always include information about the version of jqGrid which you use.

I suppose that you use ASMX-WebMethod. In the case you should include the following parameters

```js
gridview: true,
autoencode: true,
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json"},
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
},
jsonReader: {
    root: "d.rows",
    page: "d.page",
    total: "d.total",
    records: "d.records"
}
```

Additionally you should remove all `index` properties of `colModel` and consider to use `loadonce: true` option, if you don't plan to implement server side paging.

If you have any problems with loading the data in jqGrid you should always include `loadError` callback in jqGrid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) for more details.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80964/discussion-on-answer-by-oleg-call-webmethod-from-jqgrid).