# Jqgrid how to add custom custom error to display in table

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can i add a custom error message to display in the jqgrid table if there is no data or data is not found 
is it possible do?

here is my code blow and screen grab

Code

```
  <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

         var mydata;
         var collateralid= getQueryUrlString("id");    
        console.log(collateralid);

        $(".monitoring-red").jqGrid({

            url:"json/data-"+collateralid.trim()+".json",
            data: mydata,
            datatype: "json",
             emptyrecords: "0 records found",
           postData: {
                json: JSON.stringify(mydata)
            },
            success: function(mydata, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  console.log(" data :" +mydata);  
            },
            colModel: [
                { name: 'ClientID', label: 'ClientId',width: 70, key: true,
                formatter: "showlink",
                    formatoptions: {
                        baseLinkUrl: testUrl,
                        idName: "",
                        addParam: function (options) {
                            return "clientid="+options.rowid+"-20160408" ;
                        }
                    }

                },
                { name: 'Borrower',label: 'Borrower', align:'right', width: 115 },
                { name: 'Brokerage',label: 'Brokeage', align:'right', width: 125 },
                { name: 'LoanBalance', label: 'Loan Balance',align:'right',width: 100, formatter: 'currency',
                    formatoptions: { prefix: "$", suffix: " "}},
                /*{ label: 'Value1', 
                            name: 'Value1', 
                            width: 80, 
                            sorttype: 'number', 
                            formatter: 'number',
                            align: 'right'
                        }, */
                { name: 'MaxLoanAmt', label: 'MaxLoanAmt', width: 120, sorttype: 'number' , align: "right", formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: " $", suffix: " "}},
                { name: 'AvailableCredit', label: 'Available Credit', width: 110, sorttype: 'number' , align: "right", formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: " $", suffix: " "}},
                { name: 'Watch', label:  'Watch', width: 120, sorttype: 'number' , align: "right", template: "number",formatoptions: {decimalPlaces: 9}},
                { name: 'PledgedValue', label: 'PledgedValue',width: 120, sorttype: 'number', align: "right", formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: " $", suffix: " "} },
                { name: 'AverageLTV', label: 'AverageLTV',width: 75, sorttype: 'number', align: "right", formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { prefix: "", suffix: " "} }  

            ],
            additionalProperties: ["Num1"],
            beforeProcessing: function (mydata) {
                var item, i, n = mydata.length;
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    item = mydata[i];
                    item.LoanBalance = parseFloat($.trim(item.LoanBalance).replace(",", ""));
                    item.MaxLoanAmt = parseFloat($.trim(item.MaxLoanAmtMaxLoanAmt).replace(",", ""));
                    item.AvailableCredit = parseFloat($.trim(item.AvailableCredit).replace(",", ""));
                   // item.Num1 = parseInt($.trim(item.Num1).replace(",", ""), 10);
                   // item.Num2 = parseInt($.trim(item.Num2).replace(",", ""), 10);
                }
            }, 
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            loadonce: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, editable: true },
            autoResizing: { compact: true },
            forceClientSorting: true,
            sortname: "Symbol",
            height:"auto",
            caption: "<b>Collateral Monitoring Red</b>",
           viewrecords: true,


            errorDisplayTimeout: '', //never expire

                 loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
                $errorDiv = $(this.grid.eDiv),
                $errorSpan = $errorDiv.children(".ui-jqgrid-error");

            $errorSpan.html("My custom error message");
            $errorDiv.show();
            if (p.errorDisplayTimeout) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $errorSpan.empty();
                    $errorDiv.hide();
                }, p.errorDisplayTimeout);
            }
        },



            loadComplete: function () {
                var $self = $(this),
                    sum = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "Price", false, "sum"),
                    sum1 = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "MaxLoanAmt", false, "sum");

                $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {invdate: "Total:", Price: sum, maxLoanAmt: sum1});
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There `loadError` callback since a long time. [The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969114/315935) for example shows how it could be used. The main problem was that **it was no default implementation** of the callback fill jqGrid 4.12.1 (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README4.12.1.md#main-new-features-and-improvements-implemented-in-the-version-4121)). Thus the user could see some error message if loading failed.

On the other side I see that the usage of new `div.ui-jqgrid-errorbar` and the SPAN `span.ui-jqgrid-error` is not yet described. Thus I created [the simple demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/useErrorDiv.htm) for you, which demonstrates it. Additionally I use `errorDisplayTimeout` option set to 3 sec which can be combined with the error div. The corresponding code is

```
errorDisplayTimeout: 3000,
loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        $errorDiv = $(this.grid.eDiv),
        $errorSpan = $errorDiv.children(".ui-jqgrid-error");

    $errorSpan.html("My custom error message");
    $errorDiv.show();
    if (p.errorDisplayTimeout) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $errorSpan.empty();
            $errorDiv.hide();
        }, p.errorDisplayTimeout);
    }
}
```

In the same way you can display any other error text based on `jqXHR`, `textStatus`, `errorThrown` parameters which are forwarded to `loadError` from `error` callback of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

If you want to use the same div to display error message on no data you can do this in the same way. It's important to understand that no data will be not interpreted as an error. Thus `loadComplete` instead of `loadError` will be called. Inside of the `loadComplete` callback you still can examine the total number of rows (`$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "records")`) or the number of rows on the current page (`$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "reccount")`) and to display your custom message in the same way like you could display it inside of `loadError`.

**UPDATED:** I added new method `displayErrorMessage` to the latest code on GitHub to simplify working with error div (see [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/d1c3121b549a970d216ae6385638f62fffc9d3bd)). [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/useErrorDiv1.htm) use the new method and the code of `loadError` are reduced to one line:

```
errorDisplayTimeout: 3000,
loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $(this).jqGrid("displayErrorMessage", "My custom error message");
}
```

Comment: added the loadError section to my code and updated it. It didnt display the custom error message instead of the regular 404. Do I need to update my library links?

Comment: @user244394: Sorry, but the code which you post don't contains even `<script>...</script>` over the JavaScript code. I posted you two demos: one which use free jqGrid 4.13.2 and another which use the latest code from GitHub. You can see that it works. If you want that I help you to find the error in your code then you should post URL to your demo.

Comment: -Thank you i got it to work for most part here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/dc62L37z/7/  Is there anyway to change the background color of defauli error from red?  Also, how can I add a custom message when there is no data is returned?

Comment: @user244394: You are welcome! The last your demo seems to have the exact code which I posted in my answer. About changing or removing red color: the color come from `gridError: "ui-state-error"` property of the default `guiStyles: "jQueryUI"`. You can define your own guiStyle base of the standard one. For example to remove `"ui-state-error"` one can use `$.jgrid.guiStyles.jQueryCustom = { baseGuiStyle: "jQueryUI", gridError: "" };` and to add `guiStyle: "jQueryCustom"` option to the grid. See [the demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/useErrorDiv2.htm).

Comment: Oleg - I am have additional sets of data that I have added here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/dc62L37z/9/  for example Name to Contactnumber , which I do not want to display in the table. I plan to display those data in the webpage but outside the table. Is there any way of displaying outside the table without making another ajax call just for that?

Comment: @user244394: Yes you can. You need just include the names of the properties in `additionalProperties` array. The properties will be saved in the local `data` of the grid. You can use `getLocalRow` to access the data.

Comment: Is there an example on how to go about using it? to show in the page outside jqtabletable grid thanks

Comment: @user244394: Sorry, but all the discussion is far and for from your original question. I'm not sure what exactly you want to implement. It's better that you post new question where you describe clear the problem, which you can't solve. You wrote "I plan to display those data in the webpage but outside the table.". It could be to display a "details" grid for example below of the grid *on selection the row* of the main grid, but I guess only what you need.